# Hide view when listview scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll

Im trying to hide one view when listview scrolling
Its hard to make its work correctly - so i need help if possible

I have structure
1)CustomActionBar (relativelayout)
2)view (id=1) which need hide by scroll
3)header of listview (its just relative layout with some tabs id=2)
4) listview items

here my code for detecting top down scroll in listview

```
inboxListview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    y = motionEvent.getY();
                    prev_y = y;
                    dy= y;
                    Logger.e("prev y = "+prev_y);
                }
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    Logger.e("DY = "+dy);
                    dy = motionEvent.getY();
                    Logger.e("DY2 = "+dy);
                    if(dy<prev_y) {
                        Logger.e("move down 2");
                        float temp = dy-prev_y;
                        HomeActivity.changeListener.onScrollListenerHelper(1,temp);
                    }

                    if(dy>prev_y) {
                        Logger.e("move up 2");
                        float temp = dy-prev_y;
                        HomeActivity.changeListener.onScrollListenerHelper(2,temp);
                    }


                    prev_y = dy;
                    Logger.e("prev y new = "+prev_y);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private float y;
    private float dy;
    private float prev_y;
```

and my callback where im trying to hide view

```
 @Override
    public void onScrollListenerHelper(final int direction, final float ScrollYOffset) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (direction == 1) {
                    //move view up
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) topLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    int margin = params.topMargin;
                    params.topMargin = (margin + (int) ScrollYOffset);
                    Logger.e("TOP MARGIN " + params.topMargin);
                    Logger.e("RESUTL: " + (topLayout.getHeight() - topBar.getHeight()));
                    if (params.topMargin <= -(topLayout.getHeight() - topBar.getHeight())) {
                        params.topMargin = -(topLayout.getHeight() - topBar.getHeight());
                    }
                    topLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                }

                if (direction == 2) {
                    //move view down
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) topLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    int margin = params.topMargin;
                    params.topMargin = (margin + (int) ScrollYOffset);
                    Logger.e("TOP MARGIN2 " + params.topMargin);
                    if (params.topMargin >= topBar.getHeight()) {
                        params.topMargin = topBar.getHeight();
                    }
                    topLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

in some way its work. Not good but working . Problem its when i scrolling listview - on screen its look like jumping topdown.
Can any help me to improve my code ?
[image: prototype]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorExamples